# How can I resize a poster image in Latex (media9 package) while keeping the original media size?

Tags: scaling, posters, media9

I would like to use LaTeX with the Media9 package to make a pdf with embedded u3d files where each has a poster image that is scalable independently of the size of the media.

I have already tried to include scaling for the poster image, but it rescales the entire media to fit the image size. I have also tried to insert scaling parameters directly before the u3d, but end up with errors.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includemedia[
    %activate=pageopen,
    %width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth,
    3Dtoolbar, %same as `controls'
    label=model.u3d,
    3Dmenu,
    3Daac=60, 3Droll=0.000000, 3Dc2c=0.000000 865.697388 0.000000, 
    3Droo=-35, 3Dcoo=-0.000552 0.002615 25.093105,
    3Dlights=CAD,
]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{model.png}}{model.u3d}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Welcome! If I understand right, you want a zoomed part of the poster graphics be shown. You could play with the `viewport`, `width` and `height` options of `\includegraphics`. Also, don't forget to add `clip` to the aforementioned options.

Comment: Instead of `viewport`, the `trim` option could be used to crop the poster image at its edges. Cf. the `graphics` manual `grfguide.pdf`.

Comment: Thanks. My main goal is to have a poster image that I can scale down to 1/3 of its original size, while keeping the viewport (that allows manipulation of the 3D model) a larger size. Perhaps this could be accomplished by adding padding to the sides of the poster image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Alex G. In order to solve the problem, I added the trim option to "reverse" crop the poster image by using negative values.

```
\includemedia[
    %activate=pageopen,
    %width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth,
    3Dtoolbar, %same as `controls'
    label=model.u3d,
    3Dmenu,
    3Daac=60, 3Droll=0.000000, 3Dc2c=0.000000 865.697388 0.000000, 
    3Droo=-35, 3Dcoo=-0.000552 0.002615 25.093105,
    3Dlights=CAD,
]{\includegraphics[scale=1, trim=-25 -25 -25 -25, clip]{model.png}}{model.u3d}
```